# Twitter Streaming (Twitter 4j api) using apache spark streaming and java

Tags: twitter, filter, spark-streaming, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I want to get tweets from users who speak of a certain service/good/product which is available in `city x`. Supposed `city x` is `New York`, and the service is the about `law and order`. Is it more efficient to filter the tweets using user location or using keywords containing the city name(`New York`) and the service name(`law and order`) or hashtags (`#NewYork`, `#Law`, `#Order`)?

Answer (score 0):

Some research indicates only 2% of the tweets are geotagged. So I would use cityname ("New York") with hastags to be sure.